# Does EESS#1 NTRUEncrypt use the PKCS#1 MGF (mask generation function)?

Tags: standards, ntru, pkcs1

I downloaded the 1st-round NTRUEncrypt submission from NIST website, the spec mentions the mask generation function MGF1 in ASN.1 definition but not in algorithm description.

Does the EESS#1 NTRUEncrypt use the MGF1 specified in PKCS#1 at all?

Comment: The more I read it, the more I get convinced that it is a copy / paste issue, as XOF either SHAKE or AES in counter mode is used.